# How do I avoid CS0103 errors in Visual Studio when using Source Generators?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sourcegenerators

I've written a really simple source generator:

```
public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
{
    var sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder(@"
        using System;
        namespace Injector.ConsoleApp;
    
        public partial class Program
        {
           static void HelloFrom(string name)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(""Hello from "" + name);
           }
        }
    ");
    
    context.AddSource("helloWorldGenerator", SourceText.From(sourceBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
}
```

It compiles, runs and behaves exactly as I'd hope and expect, but...

[image: VS is not happy]

Visual Studio is unaware of the generated function and shows a CS0103 error. How can I get VS to not show an error for this?

Comment: If you're getting that error, the source generator is not running as you'd expect. If it was, you wouldn't be getting that compilation error. Make sure you've done a full rebuild.

Comment: You are missing a "Using" statement at the top of the module.  In this case the one where HelloFrom is located.

Comment: Also make sure is HellFrom is static, delete bin and obj folders too

Comment: Thanks @canton7. I've rebuilt the solution, but same issue occurs.

Comment: @Simon You should be able to browse to the generated source in the Solution Explorer window (under Packages, select your SG, then keep expanding to find the sources). Can you find it? Your screenshot also doesn't have enough lines for me to check that both of your `Program` partial declarations are in the same namespace

Comment: @canton7 - Thanks - Your suggestion to  browse to the generated source in the  VS Solution Explorer window was helpful in leading me to the answer.  I'm still a bit puzzled though - that generated file seems to be generated once when VS starts and then isn't regenerated if the source generator is changed. I'm going to investigate, but I think there might be another SO question coming! :-)

Comment: Yeah, known issue: VS caches the SG pretty aggressively once it's loaded. See [#48083](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48083) (and some of [#49249](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49249)). It's much easier to develop an SG using unit tests

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The solution was to change:

```
context.AddSource("helloWorldGenerator"...
```

to

```
context.AddSource("Program"...
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter -- the name of the generated file has no bearing on anything

Comment: @canton7 - That's what I'd assumed, but it really does affect VS.  I can reliably break and fix it by changing that value!

Comment: No, something else is going on, for sure